# SQL merge multiple selects on table (trigger inserted)

Tags: sql, select, merge, using

I am new to the forum and am looking for help with my SQL trigger.

The trigger monitors the table tbl_adresse whether something has changed or a new data line has been added.

My SQL trigger should collect data and write it in a new table.
This works so far with this code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [tgr_TEST] ON [dbo].[tbl_adresse]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
        MERGE [dbo].[WAWIDL_ADRESSKORREKTUR_RECHNUNGSADRESSE] AS WDL
        USING (SELECT d.* FROM tbl_adresse AS d JOIN inserted AS i ON i.kAdresse = d.kAdresse) AS WWW
            ON      TBL.XML_tadresse_kAdresse = WWW.kAdresse
            AND     TBL.XML_tadresse_kKundenID = WWW.kKundenID
        WHEN    MATCHED
            AND (
                    ISNULL(TBL.XML_tadresse_cFirma,0)           != ISNULL(WWW.cFirma,0) OR
                    ISNULL(TBL.XML_tadresse_cZusatz,0)          != ISNULL(WWW.cZusatz,0) OR
                    ISNULL(TBL.XML_tadresse_cTitel,0)           != ISNULL(WWW.cTitel,0) OR
                    ISNULL(TBL.XML_tadresse_cVorname,0)         != ISNULL(WWW.cVorname,0) OR
                    ISNULL(TBL.XML_tadresse_cName,0)            != ISNULL(WWW.cName,0) OR
                    ISNULL(TBL.XML_tadresse_cStrasse,0)         != ISNULL(WWW.cStrasse,0) OR
                    ISNULL(TBL.XML_tadresse_cPLZ,0)             != ISNULL(WWW.cPLZ,0) OR
                    ISNULL(TBL.XML_tadresse_cOrt,0)             != ISNULL(WWW.cOrt,0) OR
                    ISNULL(TBL.XML_tadresse_cAdressZusatz,0)    != ISNULL(WWW.cAdressZusatz,0)
                )
        THEN
            UPDATE
                SET
                    TBL.WDL_cKundenNr                           = '',
                    TBL.WDL_cBestellNr                          = '',

                    TBL.XML_tadresse_cFirma                     = ISNULL(WWW.cFirma,''),
                    TBL.XML_tadresse_cZusatz                    = ISNULL(WWW.cZusatz,''),
                    TBL.XML_tadresse_cTitel                     = ISNULL(WWW.cTitel,''),
                    TBL.XML_tadresse_cVorname                   = ISNULL(WWW.cVorname,''),
                    TBL.XML_tadresse_cName                      = ISNULL(WWW.cName,''),
                    TBL.XML_tadresse_cStrasse                   = ISNULL(WWW.cStrasse,''),
                    TBL.XML_tadresse_cPLZ                       = ISNULL(WWW.cPLZ,''),
                    TBL.XML_tadresse_cOrt                       = ISNULL(WWW.cOrt,''),
                    TBL.XML_tadresse_cAdressZusatz              = ISNULL(WWW.cAdressZusatz,'')
        WHEN    NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN
            INSERT  (
                    XML_tadresse_kAdresse,
                    XML_tadresse_kKundenID,
                    WDL_cKundenNr,
                    WDL_cBestellNr,
                    XML_tadresse_cFirma,
                    XML_tadresse_cZusatz,
                    XML_tadresse_cTitel,
                    XML_tadresse_cVorname,
                    XML_tadresse_cName,
                    XML_tadresse_cStrasse,
                    XML_tadresse_cPLZ,
                    XML_tadresse_cOrt,
                    XML_tadresse_cAdressZusatz
                    )
            VALUES  (
                    WWW.kAdresse,
                    WWW.kKundenID,
                    '',
                    '',
                    ISNULL(WWW.cFirma,''),
                    ISNULL(WWW.cZusatz,''),
                    ISNULL(WWW.cTitel,''),
                    ISNULL(WWW.cVorname,''),
                    ISNULL(WWW.cName,''),
                    ISNULL(WWW.cStrasse,''),
                    ISNULL(WWW.cPLZ,''),
                    ISNULL(WWW.cOrt,''),
                    ISNULL(WWW.cAdressZusatz,'')
                    );
END
GO
```

Unfortunately I am now missing more information, which I only get from a second table called tbl_orders.

I have now tried to make another JOIN, but it does not work, I get the error message that the connection is already busy, there are probably 2 queries being made at the same time.

"Die Verbindung ist mit Ergebnissen von einem anderen hstmt belegt."

```
CREATE TRIGGER [tgr_TEST] ON [dbo].[tbl_adresse]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
        MERGE [dbo].[WAWIDL_ADRESSKORREKTUR_RECHNUNGSADRESSE] AS WDL
        USING (SELECT d.* FROM tbl_adresse AS d JOIN inserted AS i ON i.kAdresse = d.kAdresse) AS WWW JOIN tbl_orders AS o ON WWW.kAdresse = o.kAdresse
            ON      TBL.XML_tadresse_kAdresse = WWW.kAdresse
            AND     TBL.XML_tadresse_kKundenID = WWW.kKundenID
        WHEN    MATCHED
            AND (
                    ISNULL(TBL.XML_tadresse_cFirma,0)           != ISNULL(WWW.cFirma,0) OR
                    ISNULL(TBL.XML_tadresse_cZusatz,0)          != ISNULL(WWW.cZusatz,0) OR
                    ISNULL(TBL.XML_tadresse_cTitel,0)           != ISNULL(WWW.cTitel,0) OR
                    ISNULL(TBL.XML_tadresse_cVorname,0)         != ISNULL(WWW.cVorname,0) OR
                    ISNULL(TBL.XML_tadresse_cName,0)            != ISNULL(WWW.cName,0) OR
                    ISNULL(TBL.XML_tadresse_cStrasse,0)         != ISNULL(WWW.cStrasse,0) OR
                    ISNULL(TBL.XML_tadresse_cPLZ,0)             != ISNULL(WWW.cPLZ,0) OR
                    ISNULL(TBL.XML_tadresse_cOrt,0)             != ISNULL(WWW.cOrt,0) OR
                    ISNULL(TBL.XML_tadresse_cAdressZusatz,0)    != ISNULL(WWW.cAdressZusatz,0)
                )
        THEN
        UPDATE
            SET
                TBL.WDL_cKundenNr                           = ISNULL(WWW.cKundenNr,''),
                TBL.WDL_cBestellNr                          = ISNULL(WWW.cBestellNr,''),
                TBL.XML_tadresse_cFirma                     = ISNULL(WWW.cFirma,''),
                TBL.XML_tadresse_cZusatz                    = ISNULL(WWW.cZusatz,''),
                TBL.XML_tadresse_cTitel                     = ISNULL(WWW.cTitel,''),
                TBL.XML_tadresse_cVorname                   = ISNULL(WWW.cVorname,''),
                TBL.XML_tadresse_cName                      = ISNULL(WWW.cName,''),
                TBL.XML_tadresse_cStrasse                   = ISNULL(WWW.cStrasse,''),
                TBL.XML_tadresse_cPLZ                       = ISNULL(WWW.cPLZ,''),
                TBL.XML_tadresse_cOrt                       = ISNULL(WWW.cOrt,''),
                TBL.XML_tadresse_cAdressZusatz              = ISNULL(WWW.cAdressZusatz,'')
    WHEN    NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN
        INSERT  (
                XML_tadresse_kAdresse,
                XML_tadresse_kKundenID,
                WDL_cKundenNr,
                WDL_cBestellNr,
                XML_tadresse_cFirma,
                XML_tadresse_cZusatz,
                XML_tadresse_cTitel,
                XML_tadresse_cVorname,
                XML_tadresse_cName,
                XML_tadresse_cStrasse,
                XML_tadresse_cPLZ,
                XML_tadresse_cOrt,
                XML_tadresse_cAdressZusatz
                )
        VALUES  (
                WWW.kAdresse,
                WWW.kKundenID,
                ISNULL(WWW.cKundenNr,''),
                ISNULL(WWW.cBestellNr,''),
                ISNULL(WWW.cFirma,''),
                ISNULL(WWW.cZusatz,''),
                ISNULL(WWW.cTitel,''),
                ISNULL(WWW.cVorname,''),
                ISNULL(WWW.cName,''),
                ISNULL(WWW.cStrasse,''),
                ISNULL(WWW.cPLZ,''),
                ISNULL(WWW.cOrt,''),
                ISNULL(WWW.cAdressZusatz,'')
                );
```

What am I doing wrong?
Can't you add any more JOIN tables at INSERTED?

Thank You!

Comment: Why did you put the new join outside the parentheses?

Comment: You mean like this? The same error: `USING (SELECT d.* FROM tbl_adresse AS d JOIN inserted AS i ON i.kAdresse = d.kAdresse JOIN tbl_orders AS o ON WWW.kAdresse = o.kAdresse) AS WWW`

Comment: At the beginning, I also had a solution that called up a SELECT for the INSERT. However, this SELECT statement cannot call up the data at this point and leaves the column empty.

For this reason I wanted to join the missing tables directly in the MERGE USING command.

My old attempt, which leaves the column empty:
`...
         THEN
             UPDATE
                 SET
                     TBL.WDL_cBestellNr = ISNULL((SELECT o.cBestellNr FROM tbl_orders AS o WHERE (o.kAdresse = JTL.kAdresse)), ''),
... `

Comment: Can nobody help?